# React Error Boundary doesn't catch runtime error

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-query, react-suspense

My code looks like this:

```
const routes = (
  <Switch>
    <Route path='*' component={Test} />
  </Switch>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <React.Suspense fallback={LoadingElement}>
        <I18nextProvider i18n={i18}>
          <QueryClientProvider client={reactQueryClient}>
            <Provider store={store}>
              <ConnectedRouter history={history}>{routes}</ConnectedRouter>
            </Provider>
          </QueryClientProvider>
        </I18nextProvider>
      </React.Suspense>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

If there's a runtime issue with `Test`, the ErrorBoundary doesn't catch it.
However, if i move the ErrorBoundary to wrap `Test` itself, it does catch it.

Why is it not catching the error if put at the highest app level like in the code snippet above?